# Using CSS and Divs to make a two-column layout

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm still relatively new to css positioning, but have read a few books and watched a few tutorials. I made some palettes over at colourLovers, and wanted to see how they would look when applied to a website as a color scheme. So, using the little coding knowledge I had, I created a page to demonstrate my color scheme. After a while, it became a sort of self-confidence boost, and I've gotten just about done with it when a little thing caught my attention.

I have a two-column layout - on the left, there is the navigation menu, with a header above and a content section to the right, all in their own divs. My question is this - when I scale the page (as in, make the window for viewing it smaller), the content section gets pushed so it wraps under the Div. The way I could fix this was to make an additional div with no bg color and make it as long as the content that contained the navigation div, so they would line up, but it doesn't fix it if you resize the window.

I'm sure there's an easy fix to this, but my limited knowledge doesn't yet know it. If it helps, I've attached an image file below of what the site looks like in my editor (Coda). I also provide a link to the code of that page of my site which I've uploaded to textsnip. You can find it here - http://textsnip.com/f434fd. I have added comments to mark the header, sidebar, and content sections as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: Personally I tend to have divs for layout, and a child div in each. The parent divs (defining the layout) are positioned absolutely - so the width and height is defined in pixels. The child divs are also positioned absolutely but have padding, margin, border and content. This means the padding, margin and border will not stretch the parent divs, so they will display exactly how you want them and should not drop down to the next line when the viewport is made smaller. Another way is to use jQuery to detect resize (use `$(window).resize(function() {});`) and then resize everything as required.

Comment: If this is what you're looking for then I will post it as an answer so you can mark this as solved.

Comment: Hmm, alright. I currently have the divs width defined in pixels for the navigation, but the other content and header divs have percentage-based widths. The header also has a fixed height, but the content div doesn't. I don't mind if the text is scaled to a new line in the content section, I just don't want those new lines to wrap underneath my navigation menu. My first thought was to extend the parent div for the navigation to the bottom of the page, but that also adds a scrollbar to the whole page, even though there's no content left. Any way to prevent content from wrapping under divs?

Comment: You don't actually ask a question.  You make a bunch of statements, even though at one point you says "My question is this" and then go on to not ask a question.  You would also do well to use jsfiddle.net to post your HTML, CSS, Javascript, questions so that people can fiddle with it.

Comment: I looked at the source, but you are obviously using a WYSIWYG editor. Code from those is generally very ugly and not very representative of the content.  Are you interested in coding this by hand? I have copied your source over to jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BSAAu/1/

Comment: @TMB, you copied the source to the JavaScript frame.. lol.

Comment: also you should use the `nav` element for navigation elements.

Comment: @TMB - nav is Html5, if you're not writing Html5, you shouldn't use nav.

Comment: No, actually Coda is a hand-code editor and doesn't feature any WYSIWYG options. You can take a look at it here - panic.com/coda.Sorry for posting it in the wrong place, I wasn't really sure where I should.

Comment: Here, I created a quick image demo to show what I mean. http://postimage.org/image/2vypcj1yc/ Basically, I don't want content from Content div to wrap underneath Nav div. I want a clear space beneath Nav div for the bg color of the page to show through.

Comment: no, it was me that put it in the javascript frame, I wasn't really paying attention.

Comment: Alright, dug around a lot on Google and found this post on techrepublic - http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-css-floats-to-create-a-three-column-page-layout/5160911 - in a comment, someone appears to be having the same problem I do, where the content div extends past the sidebar divs. If someone could kind of go off of that and explain their "solution" to me, that would be awesome. Thanks again for all of the replies!

Comment: In the end, I just decided to go with a fixed layout using css positioning with pixels, which was a whole lot easier to do. Thanks for everyone who contributed to my question, and if anyone does find a solution, it'd be much appreciated if you'd let me know. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use min-wdith on your container:

```
<div style="width: 90%; padding: 10px; margin:0 auto; min-width: 400px;">
```

This won't work on IE6, but will work on everything else.  And, if you need IE6, then there are several workarounds that will solve it.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141148/css-two-column-div-layout-misaligns-when-zoom-changes ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **%** value instead of **px**.
For example:

- Header: 100%;
- Nav: 20%;
- Content: 80%;
- Footer: 100%;

This way, if someone rize the window, it will always display perfect.

Comment: I originally had the navigation set at 20% width, but it got a little too big as I scaled the window, so I set it back to 200px. The width for the navigation div is set at 100%, but the content div wrapped underneath it, so I put a margin-bottom style of 300px on the nav div, which worked a little but when the window was shrunk, pushed the content div still underneath, just with a 300px space. The resize isn't what I'm focusing on, it's the fact that I'd like to create a column on the left that nothing can wrap in from other divs.

Comment: This question make help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380610/css-with-one-fixed-width-column-and-another-100-width

Answer (score 0):

Use "float: right" on content DIV. And replace px width with %.
[Check out this](http://textsnip.com/a47a66)

Comment: Hm, I tried that but it only extended the Navigation Div to fill the entire page's width and pushed all of content div beneath it. Thanks for the quick answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Media Queries to adjust things as they get bigger and smaller. For instance, if you wrap your entire page with a div with an ID of wrapper (and use Simon Arnold's solution for the width of the individual elements), then you can do this:

```
@media (min-width:1200px) {
   #wrapper {
     width:1100px;
   }
}
@media (max-width:1200px) {
   #wrapper {
      width:90%;
   }
}
```

These set your wrapper to 90% if the screen size is less than 1200px, and 1100px if your screen is bigger than 1200px. Thus, if the browser is wider than 1200px then your page will stay the same size, and if it's smaller then it'll flow nicely.

```
@media (max-width:700px) {
   #wrapper {
      width:100%;
    }
}
```

That one makes it wider when the browser gets smaller, and

```
@media (max-width:400px) {
   #wrapper {
     width:400px;
   }
}
```

that one sets it to a fixed width when the browser gets really small. Those are really simple queries, if you're interested in learning more about media queries then here's a good place: http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/
And of course, it wouldn't hurt to make the page flow between those transitions using CSS3 Transitions.

IE8 and below, unfortunately, do not support media queries. BUT you could read their browser type with PHP instead, and direct them to get a decent browser... It'd help make the web better. ;)